# Send data from HTML form to Express API

Tags: javascript, html, express

I'm trying to build a login page for users and need to send the login info to my express server. I'm not too sure about how to call the api for my server and send the information across though.
Right now I get a 405 error method not allowed when I try to submit the form by clicking on the button.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html land="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
    <script src="../app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="login.html">To login</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html land="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login page</title><br><br>
    <script src="../app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="login-form" method="post" action="/login">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username-field" placeholder="Username" required><br><br>
      <!-- TODO: Change type to "password" -->
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password-field" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login-form-submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({"extended": true}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send({ 'body': req.body });
});

// Listen on port 3000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server listening at http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
});
```

Comment: One thing that's odd is that `app.js` is your server, but you seem to be including it in your HTML page.  That `app.js` will only work in the server, not in a browser.  Look for any console errors in the browser.

Comment: Also, you are accessing the server at localhost:3000, correct?  i.e that's the page you are visiting in your browser?

Comment: your code looks fine. Try to  run the express server first then submit your form

Comment: @user2740650 when I run my server then open a browser page to http://localhost:3000/login it says 404 error cannot GET /login

Comment: I want to submit some form from an HTML page and have the express server process it. However, I'm not sure how to send a request using HTML forms.

Comment: How would I get the app.js to work with the browser as well? Can HTML send a post request from the form? @user2740650

Comment: "cannot GET /login " is because you have support for post via `app.post('/login'...`, but you'd need to respond to the /login with a handler for `app.get('/login'...`.  Also you didn't mention about console errors and why you are including app.js from your HTML.

Comment: I think you could benefit from going through a tutorial.  There are many.  Here's one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript. Add this to your `login.html` file

```html
<script type="text/javascript" >
async function login(){
  // Get values from FORM
  let username = document.getElementById("username-field")
  let password = document.getElementById("password-field")

  // Body payload
  let body = { username, password }

  // Fetch options
  let option = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  // Call /login as POST and wait for reply
  const response = await fetch(`/login`, options)
  const json = await response.json()

  // Use json response
  alert(json)
}

document.getElementById("login-form-submit").addEventListener("click", login);
</script>
```

In order for the server to be properly up, you need to make sure you run it as `node app.js` instead of adding it to the html file.

**UPDATE:**
Check out this repo for a working solution : https://github.com/rui-costa/stackoverflow-68238492

Comment: I don't think my express /login api is ever invoked when I set the onSubmit=login().

Comment: My server says it's listening but doesn't respond to any API requests.

Comment: Check this [repo](https://github.com/rui-costa/stackoverflow-68238492).
This should be able to solve your problem. Otherwise we need to investigate deeper.